# Render Razor tag within a Model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I have a hidden field called `someHiddenField` in my razor view. I am dynamically populating a list of items, for which each item in the list has a href. I need the link in href to pass `someHiddenField` as an argument in the link. That is, the rendered HTML should look like

```
<li>
    <a href="http://someURL.com?Value=someHiddenField">
    Item 1</a>
</li>
```

The links in the href come from a Model. Say, `@Model.Link`. So in the razor view

```
<a href="http://someURL.com?Value=someHiddenField">
```

will be substituted by

```
<a href="@Model.Link">
```

where `@Model.Link` has `"http://someURL.com?Value=@Model.someHiddenField"`
But when my html is rendered, it gives me

```
<a href="http://someURL.com?Value=@Model.someHiddenField">
```

How do I get `@Model.someHiddenField` to get rendered and give me the desired link?

Comment: ``Value=@(Model.someHiddenField)``

Comment: Why would you need a hidden input (makes no sense to do so and you would need javascript to build the link in any case)? Show how you are generating the links in the view

Comment: If someHiddenField is a hidden field like @html.hidden() then from where you have been getting the value? Suppose the someHiddenField is a element of a model then you can write the code like <a href="@Model.Link?Value=@Model.someHiddenField">

Comment: An API call is made is to generate the value of `someHiddenField`. This `someHiddenField` is then assigned to a `Model` and passed to the Razor view. The lists are generated using a separate API.

Answer (score 0):

Use razor string concatenation like,

```
@(String link = Model.Link + "?Value="+ Model.someHiddenField;)
<a href="@link"></a>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot implement this solution. I do have a couple of hidden fields and not all of them are required in every link. The API goes through an XML file which gives information on which link to call for each list item. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.